# Conversion from Shape to Path in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, expression-blend

How can I change a XAML code (which represent a set of shapes) to a single figure presented by PATH?

Let's say we have XAML code such as:

```
  <Ellipse Fill="#FF0A0A0E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,184,0,0" 
           Stroke="Black" Width="8" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,187.5,0,0" 
             Stroke="Black" Width="89.5" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

and need to convert it into a single path object?

I tried using Blend 4 where it allows you to convert shaped into path but then above code was converted to:

```
<Path Data="M7.5,4 C7.5,5.9329966 5.9329966,7.5 4,7.5 C2.0670034,7.5 0.5,5.9329966 0.5,4 C0.5,2.0670034 2.0670034,0.5 4,0.5 C5.9329966,0.5 7.5,2.0670034 7.5,4 z" 
      Fill="#FF0A0A0E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" Margin="192,184,0,0" 
      Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="8"/>
<Path Data="M0.5,0.5 L89,0.5 z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" 
      Margin="152,187.5,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Width="89.5" />
```

The reason I'm asking this question is because in  I only can define only one Path. Correct me if I'm wrong. If so, then how can I embed 2 paths or more in one style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine two shapes into one `Path` with Expression Blend 4.

To do it, select both om them by holding ctrl or shift

[image]

After that, choose Object -> Combine -> Unite

And in your case it'll output this

```
<Path Data="M44,0.5 C45.932995,0.50000024 47.5,2.0670036 47.5,4.0000002 L89,4.0000002 89,4.0100003 47.499496,4.0100003 47.48193,4.3578544 C47.302696,6.122751 45.812183,7.5000002 44,7.5000002 42.187817,7.5000002 40.697304,6.122751 40.51807,4.3578544 L40.500504,4.0100003 0.5,4.0100003 0.5,4.0000002 40.5,4.0000002 C40.5,2.0670036 42.067005,0.50000024 44,0.5 z"
      Fill="Black"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Height="8"
      Margin="152,184,0,0"
      Stretch="Fill"
      Stroke="Black"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Width="89.5"/>
```

Note that there is a bug with this if the Rectangles `Height` is exactly 1. Then it will just disappear. To workaround this just set `Height` to something like 1.00001

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,187.5,0,0"  
         Stroke="Black" Width="89.5" Height="1.00001" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible to do multiple separate paths with one Data field. For instance:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L 10,10 L 20, 10 L 20,0 z M 100,5 L 110,15 L 120,15 L 120,5 z" 
      Stroke="Black" Fill="Red" />
```

However, that assumes you want the same `Fill`, `Stroke`, etc in both pieces, which is not the case in your example.